# pyside embed vim

Tags: python, vim, pyside, pygobject

I know to embed vim in a [Gtk application](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) using sockets like the following snippet

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import subprocess

win=Gtk.Window()
win.set_default_size(600,800)
win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
editor = Gtk.Socket()
win.add(editor)
editor.connect("plug-removed", Gtk.main_quit)
subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/gvim", \
        "--socketid", str(editor.get_id())])
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

How does one do this in [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide)? I could not find any reference to sockets in pyside.

UPDATE (using JimP's idea)

The following code embeds a gvim instance in a Pyside widget. However the gvim window does not seem to resize when to the full size of the parent window.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)    
win = QtGui.QWidget()
win.resize(600, 800)

container = QtGui.QX11EmbedContainer(win)
container.show()
QtCore.QObject.connect(container, 
    QtCore.SIGNAL("clientClosed()"), 
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
winId = container.winId()
process = QtCore.QProcess(container)
options = ["--socketid", str(winId)]
process.start("gvim", options)

win.show()    
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is there no way to do this? If not sockets, any other way is also fine. I just need to embed vim in a pyside application.

Comment: No answer doesn't mean it's impossible. Just that none of the people who saw your question knows how to do it. You should also add a link to the PySide in question. Also GVim is GTK, I'm not sure how it will work in a QT environment.

Comment: @romainl Ok....gvim may not be possible as you say. I am just looking for a way to embed vim in a pyside application. With the above code I can do it a Gtk app. But am clueless about how to achieve the same in a pyside app. About the link, I dont know the relevant code. So which link are you mentioning?

Comment: I didn't know what PySide was so I looked it up on Google. You might want to add a link or two to help people understand what you are after. Did you see [qtvim](http://gitorious.org/vim-qt)?

Comment: I updated with links. I dint know about qtvim but that seems to be written in C. I was looking for a pythonic implementation. Thanks anyway for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key to getting this working would be translating GTK speak to QT speak.  Google around your code, I see that [Gtk.Socket](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkSocket.html) says:

> The communication between a GtkSocket and a GtkPlug follows the XEmbed
>   protocol. This protocol has also been implemented in other toolkits,
>   e.g. Qt, allowing the same level of integration when embedding a Qt
>   widget in GTK or vice versa.

So then the question becomes what does QT call their XEmbed classes?  Google around I found [QX11EmbedContainer](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QX11EmbedContainer.html) which says:

> It is possible for PySide.QtGui.QX11EmbedContainer to embed XEmbed
>   widgets from toolkits other than Qt, such as GTK+. Arbitrary
>   (non-XEmbed) X11 widgets can also be embedded, but the XEmbed-specific
>   features such as window activation and focus handling are then lost.
>
> The GTK+ equivalent of PySide.QtGui.QX11EmbedContainer is GtkSocket.
>   The corresponding KDE 3 widget is called QXEmbed.

I'm not running PySide at the moment, but that page on [QX11EmbedContainer](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QX11EmbedContainer.html) contains some example C++ code that I think will get you where you need to be.  You will need to translate the C++ to Python, but I don't that will be too hard.

Comment: Excellent..! Almost there. I updated with the new code. There is one problem. The embedded gvim instance does not resize when I resize the parent window. I am sure that this is something simple but dont know what.